# Getting an intersection between 2 CIDR spaces when you have huge data sets

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, inetaddress

Basically, I have a list of IP subnets (`supernets`) which contains around 100 elements. In the same time, I have another list (`ips`) which contains around 300k of IP addresses/networks.

Example:

```
supernets = ['10.10.0.0/16',  '12.0.0.0/8']

ips = ['10.10.10.1', '10.10.10.8/30', '12.1.1.0/24']
```

The end goal is to classify the IP addresses based upon where they fall in the supernet.

So what I did is to compare every IP addresses/network element in the 2nd list to the first element in the supernet lists and so on.

Baically, I do this:

```
for i in range(len(supernets)):
    for x in ips:
        if IPNetwork(x) in IPNetwork(sorted(supernets)[i]):
            print(i, x, sorted(supernets)[i])
            lod[i][sorted(supernets)[i]].append(x)
```

This works fine, but it take ages and the CPU goes crazy, so my question is, is there any methodology or clean code that can achieve this and save time?

> UPDATE
>
> I have sorted the lists and used list comprehension instead, and the
>   script took around 11mins to run which is a good optimization in terms
>   of speed. But the CPU is still 100% during the whole 11mins.

```
[lod[i][public[i]].append(x) for i in range(len(public)) for x in ips if IPNetwork(x) in IPNetwork((public)[i])]
```

Comment: Since your process is CPU intensive, seems to be something for [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) rather than multi threading. Check [this](https://link.medium.com/sh5RFKtIBR)

Comment: // , What research have you done for this already, before you decided to ask the question here?

Comment: How are you comparing the IPs and subnets?

Comment: Sort once, store it and then work. You could also store everything as some IP object instance from [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html). Then your workflow just needs to compare.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I added code snip

Comment: @Cheche I will try this, thanks.

Comment: @MohamedKamal test it and tell me if it takes less time to finish. After that you could try [multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) to make it faster.

Comment: @Cheche I have sorted them into 2 structures and compared them using list comprehensions instead of for loop and the time it takes have improved by around 40%. It tool 662.327051163sec now instead of ~20mins.

Comment: Can you update your post with the new code?, we could try multiprocessing then!